# Generalized Difference in Differences model: time*group interaction contradicts lift

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, causality, stan, generalized-did

I've constructed a Bayesian Generalized Difference in Differences model. I model an intercept as well as three coefficients; one for treatment_group assignment, one for post-start period, and one for the interaction of treatment_group assignment and post_start period (aka exposure.)

First, I'd like to validate that I've done this appropriately. And second, I have a question below about the output. Namely, I'm curious how my lift can be positive but my interaction term could be negative?

Note that, pre-experiment, the control group had a lower rate (K/N) than the treatment group but post experiment, the control group had a higher rate. So it appears that the time period effect might have been stronger for the control group than the treatment group.

I understand that GDD is designed for this use case. But I'm also confused how it could handle this when there are no observations of the treatment group without exposure during the post-start period.

```
bayesian_model = """
// GDD
data {
    int<lower=0> N;                 
    int<lower=0,upper=1> treatment_group[N];
    int<lower=0,upper=1> post_start[N];
    int<lower=0> successes[N]; 
    int<lower=0> trials[N];     
}

parameters {
    real alpha;          
    real beta_treatment_group; 
    real beta_post_start;
    real gamma_exposure; 
}

model {
    // priors
    alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
    beta_treatment_group ~ normal(0, 10);
    beta_post_start ~ normal(0, 10);
    gamma_exposure ~ normal(0, 10);    
    
    
    // likelihood
    for (i in 1:N) {
        successes[i] ~ binomial_logit(trials[i],        alpha 
                                                       +treatment_group[i]*beta_treatment_group 
                                                       +post_start[i]*beta_post_start
                                                       +treatment_group[i]*post_start[i]*gamma_exposure);
    }
}
    
generated quantities {
  real lift;
  lift = inv_logit(alpha + beta_treatment_group + beta_post_start + gamma_exposure) - inv_logit(alpha + beta_post_start);
}
```

And here is the output of the sampler

```
                        mean    sd  hdi_3%  hdi_97%     mcse_mean   mcse_sd     ess_bulk    ess_tail    r_hat
alpha                   1.135   0.038   1.064   1.206   0.001   0.001   1464.0  1985.0  1.0
beta_treatment_group    0.209   0.060   0.102   0.322   0.002   0.001   1499.0  1847.0  1.0
beta_post_start         0.252   0.052   0.155   0.348   0.001   0.001   1541.0  1931.0  1.0
gamma_exposure          -0.168  0.081   -0.311  -0.008  0.002   0.001   1655.0  1998.0  1.0
lift                     0.007  0.009   -0.010  0.022   0.000   0.000   3656.0  3211.0  1.0
```

My question is: How can I have a negative interaction term (treatment_group * post_start) gamma exposure but a positive lift?

Have I computed lift wrong?

**Edit**: In retrospect my original lift computation deviates from the traditional DiD lift computation and might not be reliable. Here is a new attempt, which I believe tis closer to the mark if not accurate- but would still appreciate feedback.

```
generated quantities {
  real pre_diff;
  real post_diff;
  real lift;  
  
  pre_diff = inv_logit(alpha + beta_treatment_group) - inv_logit(alpha);
  post_diff = inv_logit(alpha + beta_treatment_group + beta_post_start + gamma_exposure) - inv_logit(alpha + beta_post_start); 
  lift = post_diff - pre_diff;
}
```

The lift is now negative and does not contradict the exposure coefficient.